# Creating Text Decoration that Moves

Tags: javascript, html, css

how do i make a moving text decorations like [this](http://launchpad.la/) See when user hovers on "about", "companies", "blog", the line moves. Any idea how to create that? Thanks:)

Comment: a hint go to that page and right click and go to inspect elements that will explain a lot

Comment: they just adjust the background-position on hover. I would suspect js since I am not 100% sure you can have a css3 looping transition.

Comment: hi i did inspect elements. it is within a span, but there are decimals that changes. I'm pretty new to coding, so i'm not too sure. You can just give me hints on what to google. that would be great too. thank you

Comment: you are khai qing onhover they are changing border-position

Comment: google hint is border position

Comment: what is "khai qing"? Ok i will google border position. thanks

Comment: no, google hint is background-position. There's no border-position declaration that I am aware of. Look into jquery .on as well. You can set events for mouseenter and mouseleave easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS3 animations:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="test">
<h2>Some title</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, omnesque accusata pro ei. Ex vocibus pertinax facilisis mei, sit verterem adolescens ea. Ut ius tota tritani. Sumo rebum conclusionemque et usu. Duo deleniti delicata ei. Est magna graeci in, ludus officiis efficiendi ius ex.</p>
```

**CSS**:

```
#test {
    display:block;
    background:url('http://launchpad.la/wp-content/themes/launchpad-la/resources/css/images/nav-retina-red.png') repeat-x;
    width:200px;
    height:3px;
}
#test:hover {
    animation:move 3s ease-in infinite;
    -webkit-animation:move 3s ease-in infinite;
    -moz-animation:move 3s ease-in infinite;
    -ms-animation:move 3s ease-in infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
    from{background-position:0px 0px;}
    to {background-position:1000px 0px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    from{background-position:0px 0px;}
    to {background-position:1000px 0px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes move {
    from{background-position:0px 0px;}
    to {background-position:1000px 0px;}
}
@-ms-keyframes move {
    from{background-position:0px 0px;}
    to {background-position:1000px 0px;}
}
```

And here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/uHCa7/1/)**